# issue's using Vb.net as Client and PHP as Server (ï»¿)

Tags: php, vb.net

So I got these Codes.

```
<?php
    $uploaddir = "upload/";
    if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])) {
        $name = rand(1,1000000000000);
        $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($name . ".png");
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
            echo $name . ".png";
        }
        else {
            print_r($_FILES);
        } 
    }
    else {
        echo "Upload Failed!!!";
        print_r($_FILES);
    }
?>
```

And this is my VB.NET code.

```
Dim Client As System.Net.WebClient = New System.Net.WebClient
Client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "binary/octet-stream")
Dim result() As Byte = Client.UploadFile("/uploading/upload.php", "POST", filename)
Dim s As String = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result, 0, result.Length)
```

It is working all fine, the only thing is that the result I get back always adds this in front of every file ï»¿. (It's only echo'ing like that, it does properly upload on my server)
e.g /uploads/ï»¿561708579306.png While it has to be /uploads/561708579306.png
So the upload goes right, it gives the right name, which is /uploads/561708579306.png, but the echo seems to be giving this back /uploads/ï»¿561708579306.png

Does anybody have a clue?

Sincerly,
Jordy

Comment: looks like a BOM (byte order mark)

Comment: Is it fixable and how.

Comment: Have you tried echo $uploadfile; instead?  It seems to be more accurate anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, This is a BOM problem.

There are two ways I have in mind.

**save upload.php (and all other included phps) without BOM**

The only way I know how is to save it with notepad++ and choose 'encode in UTF-8 Without BOM' from encoding tab.

**Remove any other output before echo**

Which seems to be better that the other solution.
add `ob_clean();` before every echo to clean data from upper lines.

Hope it helps.